# Multiple "Refresh" buttons on Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

[image: Multiple refresh buttons]

Right clicking on a project produces multiple "Refresh" buttons. Is there a way to reset this UI and solve this bug?